# password check directive elem.add error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, events, angularjs-directive

I'm making a password checking directive to ensure password and confirm_password fields are the same:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('pwCheck', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                var password = "#" + attrs.pwCheck;
                elem.add(password).on('keyup', function() {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', elem.val() === $(password).val());
                    });
                });
            }
        };
});
```

I get a error when adding the `keyup` handler to both pw and pw check fields:

> TypeError: elem.add is not a function

So I removed `.add()` and just do

`elem.on('keyup', function() {`

Now I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I'm following [this](http://codepen.io/brunoscopelliti/pen/CctvH?editors=101) codepen. I've set the angular app correctly, and the directive logs the html elements (elem, attrs, ctrl) fine. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jQuery` is missing. But I would suggest you to use `scope` variable inside you directive that you have access to scope of controller to your directive, Because is not creating isolated scope.

**Code**

```
angular.module('myModule')
.directive('pwCheck', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var password = "#" + attrs.pwCheck;
      elem.add(password).on('keyup', function() {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', elem.val() === scope[attrs.pwCheck]);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[**Demo CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdrREr)

Comment: Can I accomplish this without jQuery? I can do `elem.bind('keyup', function() {`, but am not sure how to replicate the `add()` within angular

Comment: yes you could achieve this without DOM..but what do you mean by `.add()` method does

Comment: add() is jquery function that  adds elements to an existing group of elements.but in my case keyup event is only work for confirm password field where directive is added  when i change value in password field it does not work.How can i make it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Hope I'm not too late. 
To solve your issue just use $(elem).add

code

```
    angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('pwCheck', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                var password = "#" + attrs.pwCheck;
                $(elem).add(password).on('keyup', function() {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', elem.val() === $(password).val());
                    });
                });
            }
        };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use this directive as well. But without loading JQuery, angular uses jQLite when jQuery isn't loaded. So using  `element.append` instead of `elem.add` works.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('pwCheck', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      var password = "#" + attrs.pwCheck;
      element.append(password).on('keyup', function() {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', element.val() === scope[attrs.pwCheck]);
        });
      });
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you're loading jQuery first. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp